# Почему "допрыгался"?

Tags: этимология

В разговорной речи нередко можно услышать: "Вот он и допрыгался". Почему "допрыгался"? Есть немало глаголов с приставкой "до-" в схожем значении: доигрался, доболтался, добегался, дожился, доработался, дослужился и т. п., но их лексическое значение как-то связано с семантикой глаголов. А вот "допрыгался" употребляется в обобщенном смысле: "бездумно, безответственно относился к чему-то и получил отрицательный результат". Но почему именно "допрыгался" ?

Пять дней вопрос "висел" на сайте, но не получил никаких версий. Вряд ли в каком-либо словаре найдется объяснение причины закрепления именно данного слова в значении, о котором я писал выше. Могу предположить, что выражение пришло из детской среды. На эту мысль меня натолкнул 10-летний внук, которого я спросил о возможном объяснении смысла выражения. Максим ответил: "Мальчик прыгал, прыгал и сломал ногу. Мама ему сказала:"Ну вот, допрыгался". А может, устами младенца... В раннем детстве мы не ходим, а бегаем, прыгаем, естественно, получаем травмы из-за такой неосторожности и от взрослых получаем осуждающие реплики: "Допрыгался!". Из детства это выражение перенесено и во взрослую жизнь, но уже в значении "вел себя безрассудно, безответственно, необдуманно, поэтому потерпел неудачу в чем-то, нанес себе ущерб".

Вот такое несколько наивное объяснение придумал я. Прошу прощения у солидных форумчан, но ведь все мы родом из детства...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я одно могу сказать, "допрыгался" - далеко не едиственный вариант, едва ли не от любого глагола, означающего движение (и не только движение), даже табуированных, можно образовать нечто подобное: добегался, докрутился, довысовывался, довыступался, довыпендривался. Семантика порождающего глагола далеко не всегда сохраняется.
А "допрыгался" можно объяснить, например, конвульсивными "прыжками" жертвы перед смертью (хорошо демонстрируется на несчатных лабораторных лягушках).

Answer (score 1):

Из басни:

```
ПОПРЫГУНЬЯ Стрекоза
Лето красное пропела;
Оглянуться не успела,
```

Стрекоза вообще-то то не кузнечик. Она не прыгает, а летает. Значит здесь это слово употреблено в переносном смысле. То есть занимающаяся развлечениями, несерьезными делами. 
Дети маленькие бегают и подпрыгивают, когда играют. Всякие пляски, танцы тоже могут прыжками сопровождаться. Думаю от этого пошло. То есть заниматься ерундой, или не тем чем надо, причем активно.